# VBA Error handling, define an Error into an Error

Tags: vba, error-handling

I launch Python through a VBA macro. I want a proper error message if the Python path isn't good.
I use this macro on 2 different computers, and the Python paths are not the same on those 2 computers. The 2 paths are on 2 differents Cells name path_Python and path_Python_2
Here is my code :

```
Function launchPython() As Boolean
Dim pathScript As String

pathScript = [path_files] + "code.py"

On Error GoTo err
    Shell [path_Python].Value & " " & pathScript
    launchPython = True
    Exit Function

err:
    On Error GoTo err2
        Shell [path_Python_2].Value & " " & pathScript
        launchPython = True
err2:
    launchPython = False
    MsgBox "Error: please check Python paths"

End Function
```

Problem is, when 2 the paths are not good, instead of going to err2, I have a VBA error message blocking on

```
err:
    On Error GoTo err2
        Shell [path_Python_2].Value & " " & pathScript
```

How can I solve this ?
Thank you very much

Comment: Can you not validate the path using `IF` statements instead of handlers?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to shell a command to a potentially missing path, I would check that a file exists and try that.  You can use one of many functions such as FileExists in  http://allenbrowne.com/func-11.html, or just check that dir$ returns non blank.

```
Dim Path as string

path = path_python

if dir(path) = "" then 
  path = path_python2
  if dir(path) = "" then err.raise
end if

shell path  & " " & pathScript
```